# DataGridView column shifts after rebinding

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I add a button column through the code to the datagridview after assigning the datasource, it shows correctly after loading. then

1. Add a new row and save it to the database
2. Retrieve the data from the database
3. Populate a datatable and assign it to the datasource of the datagridview

For some reason, the button column shifts from the last to second column? Why would that happen?

Comment: can you show some sample picture(capture) ?

Comment: Thanks Toon! I need to set DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you generating columns automatically, sure you have  `DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true`

After you change `DataSource` all generated columns are removed and generated again.
But column added manually stay after generated columns was removed and index of manually added column become 0 or 1.
Then again generated columns added after manually added columns

For solution you can add all columns you need manually in the order you need and set `DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false`

Or change move button column to the place you want manually every time new DataSource is added

Comment: Thanks Fabio, DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false is the trick!!